# ESP8266 server listening on all pages

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I have simple server running on my nodeMCU and I would like to redirect all user request to one function. So that any page that will user type it will always go to the specific function.

Is there some wildcard or something?

I have tried something like this but it is not working:

```
server.on("/*",function);
server.on("*",function);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i finnaly found it

```
server.onNotFound(function)
```